# Eliminar caracter "/" al final de URL

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, virtualhost

Tengo un problema en una llamada a una `url` mediante `curl/navegador` y no se donde está el problema exactamente pues no uso ningún tipo de rewrite ni reescritura

El caso es tengo un simple `PHP` que me devuelve una **IP** pública si accedo a las siguientes `URL's`:

> http://guif.duckdns.org/ip 
>   https://guif.duckdns.org/ip

Las dos funcionan y devuelven el resultado, **PERO** se añade una **"/"** al final de la página quedando la `URL` como:

> https://guif.duckdns.org/ip/

Sabeís por qué aparece y cómo evitarlo? 
**No** uso `.htaccess`

Cómo accedo directamente a `https` añado la configuración directamente:

```
[root@srv02 conf.d]# cat ssl.conf | egrep -v '^#|^$'
Listen 443 https
SSLPassPhraseDialog exec:/usr/libexec/httpd-ssl-pass-dialog
SSLSessionCache         shmcb:/run/httpd/sslcache(512000)
SSLSessionCacheTimeout  300
SSLRandomSeed startup file:/dev/urandom  256
SSLRandomSeed connect builtin
SSLCryptoDevice builtin
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
ErrorLog logs/ssl_error_log
TransferLog logs/ssl_access_log
LogLevel warn
SSLEngine on
SSLProtocol all -SSLv3 -TLSv1 -TLSv1.1
SSLCipherSuite ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/guif.duckdns.org/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/guif.duckdns.org/privkey.pem
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/guif.duckdns.org/fullchain.pem
<Files ~ "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php3?)$">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</Files>
<Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</Directory>
BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-5]" \
         nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
         downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
CustomLog logs/ssl_request_log \
          "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b %D"
</VirtualHost>
```

Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar una regla como:

```
<Directory "/var/www/">
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
</Directory>
```

Esto debería ser de utilidad.

Comment: mismo comportamiento... añade la "/" al final

Comment: ¿Intentaste sin `RewriteBase /` y comprobaste que la ruta `/var/www/` sea la correcta? Acabo de probarlo y me funcionó sin problemas. Aquí mi configuración de VHost: https://i.imgur.com/XRIlz4B.png